# Ordered to VS Ordered From

Tags: meaning, word-choice, prepositions

Do **ordered to** and **ordered from** have different meanings?

I feel like you use **ordered from** if you have received the order already.

Use **ordered to** if you have not received the order yet.

For example,

When your friend asks "Where did you get this pizza? This is delicious!". You would say "This pizza was ordered **from** Pizza Hut"

When your parent asked you to order a pizza. After you have placed an order, your parent asks you which pizza brand you ordered and you tell them "I ordered it **to** Pizza Hut"

Is this right? Or do you use ordered *from* for both examples?

Comment: Could you please give examples of sentences you are thinking about? **Ordered from** usually describes from where *something* was ordered. I'm not sure what you mean by **order to**.

Comment: **"Ordered to"** refers to being told to perform a task by a superior. **"Ordered from"** refers to purchasing something. The two usages have nothing to do with each other. Without [**Details,**](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/439/37009) your question, unfortunately, may be closed.

Comment: I saw someone using **ordered to** to refer to purchasing something. I wasn't sure which expression is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example is fine, except you might rephrase it as "I ordered it from Pizza Hut."

In the second example, *to* does not indicate the source of the pizza. Again, for this example, you would use *from* since *from* indicates that the source of the pizza is Pizza Hut. Also, using *ordered from* does not suggest that you have the pizza in your possession at that moment. You can use it even if you have just placed the order and it's barely going to be made.

You can use *to* to indicate the destination, as in "I had the pizza delivered **to** the house." You might get away with *ordered* instead of *delivered*, but it seems a little strange in my opinion. I don't advise it.

You should use *ordered to* when someone is [*issuing a command*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/order). For example, *I was ordered to order a pizza*. This means that someone instructed you to order a pizza.